# How can I use powershell to control a program?

Tags: powershell, automation

I am trying to automate some repetitive tasks and I found that you can schedule the execution of powershell scripts which seems to be the perfect solution for me.

I managed to open a video that I need to play using the cmdlet below:

```
$video = "C:\Users\filepath\video.mp4"
start-process $video -WindowStyle Maximized -wait
```

The video opens up in VLC player with no issues, nonetheless I need to know how to get acces to that "VLC object" (I don't even know how to call it) an manipulate it (make it fullscreen, tune some settings, etc), I don't know if it can be stored in a variable for later manipulation (like you do with jQuery).

Most of the information that I have found about powershell deals with comunication between computers, installing and uninstalling apps, monitoring some indicators, etc. however I need to learn how to use powershell to actually control the apps and processes that are running in my computer, where can I find more information related to this?

I found some information about `SendKeys` method and also found how to move the cursor:

```
$Position = [system.windows.forms.cursor]::Position
[system.windows.forms.cursor]::Position = New-Object system.drawing.point(($Position.x + 800), ($Position.y + 800))
```

But honestly, I have this feeling that I'm not getting the basics of how this Powershell world is structured and what are the very basic building blocks of the syntax, so I can't start manipulating stuff yet.

Since almost everything about powershell is oriented to achieve other stuff, what should I know in order to use it for automatic app manipulation? Did I choose the wrong technology to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried looking at the vlc player argument list?

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

you can pass via the command line, something like this:

```
$vlc = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe'
$video = 'D:\sample.mp4'

Start-Process -Wait $vlc -ArgumentList "$video vlc://quit"  -WindowStyle Maximized
```

Comment: [This](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/) is an additional good source. It cotains not all, but the most important parameters in a structered layout.